# Formatting multiple datetimes into a string

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting

I'd like to format a string with two datetimes, using a particular format.

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
d2 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

daterange = [d1, d2]

fmt = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
```

I'm currently formatting the dates with `strftime` first:

```
string = "Date range: {} to {}".format(d1.strftime(fmt), d2.strftime(fmt))
```

> Date range: 2013/02/05 12:22:12 to 2013/02/04 12:22:12

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can supply the date format in the string itself:

```
string = "{0:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}".format(d1)
```

Following on from this, it's a bit cleaner if we set the format from a parameter to `format()`:

```
"Date range: {0:{2}} to {1:{2}}".format(d1, d2, fmt)
```

And we can even pass a single date range, and get all the dates from there using `0[index]`

```
"Date range: {0[0]:{1}} to {0[1]:{1}}".format(daterange, fmt)
```

We could also use named fields, for more readability:

```
"Date range: {dates[0]:{fmt}} to {dates[1]:{fmt}}".format(dates=daterange, fmt=fmt)
```

Comment: Very nice explanation, love that! :-)

Comment: @Aufwind Thanks! I think `format()` is unappreciated, so hopefully this helps to show off a bit of it's power.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this `d1.isoformat().replace('T',' ').replace('-','/')[:-7]`

`isoformat()` is pretty close to the format you have above. IE. 2013-02-04T23:53:45.174635